# PHP cURL get last page number

Tags: php, curl

I am doing php parser using cURL (simple_html_dom.php).
I have to parse news posts here: https://www.sport-express.ru/football/reviews/page2/
It is second page. I need to get programatically last number of page (it will be 50).
There is no pagination - only lazy loading button.
How can I get last page number using cURL?
Thanks!

PS: It will be great if You show also how can I get last page number when there will pagination.

Comment: The link you click to load more content, is inside a `<div class="se-material-list-page__nav" data-component="nav" data-prop-page="3" data-prop-max-page="50">` - so you can grab your "50" from there.

Comment: Thanks, CBroe. And what about getting last page number when there will pagination?

Comment: Identify the element that holds the pagination links, and then grab the last item from that. (Details may vary, depending on what structure the target site actually uses for their pagination.)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to go through all pages until the error 404 appears

```
$pageNumber = 1;
$url = "https://www.sport-express.ru/football/reviews/page{pageNumber}/?ajax=1";

$finished = false;
while($finished === false) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, str_replace($pageNumber, '{pageNumber}', $url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($httpCode === 404) {
        $finished = true;
    } else {
        // Do something...
        $pageNumber++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my original idea.  But it is very slow due to the slow page load times (≈2 seconds). So I then thought to try page 40 and if it was valid then try 50.  If not valid, try 30.  If valid, try 60.  And so on.   I guess I'm saying I like you answer.  Then I found out about the ` data-prop-max-page=`.  That made it simple and not too slow.   Although I find a page load time of 2 seconds to be unacceptable.   Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.sport-express.ru/football/reviews/page1/'); 
$start = strpos($data,'data-prop-max-page="') + 20;
echo "start=$start\n";
$end = strpos($data,'>',$start) - 1;
$lastpage = substr($data,$start,$end-$start);
echo "last page = $lastpage \n$data";
```

This is what we are looking for:

```
 <div class="se-material-list-page__nav" data-component="nav" data-prop-page="2" data-prop-max-page="50">
```

First find the position of 'data-prop-max-page='
The add 20 because the search string is 20 characters long.
Then get the the position of the `>` immediately following the $start position (third strpos parameter).
Then get the sub string which today is 50.

Here are the values found:

```
start=339441
end=339442
last page = 50
```

> PS: It will be great if You show also how can I get last page number
> when there will pagination.

Reply to my answer when that day comes.  My psychic abilities are not that sharp.